# Please identify the soundtrack Tim Pool uses at the end of his videos

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

Tim Pool has those videos on Youtube and there is a really nice song at the end that he uses but I can't identify it with Shazam.

Does anyone know what song is this?

Here is a [sample of the song](https://youtu.be/iUkWGOQnswU?t=800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an original creation, but really looks like a soundalike of **Kavinsky**'s [*Nightfall*](https://youtu.be/MV_3Dpw-BRY?t=10).

- Drums have almost exactly the same pattern.
- Similar arpeggios.
- Main melody with a flanger effect.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping it was not an OC. I started to appreciate that kind of music after an overdose of Michael McCann